# Making Date Field "Required" in SharePoint List breaks custom List Form

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a **custom new form** for SharePoint 2013 List which has multiple required field and when I click on Submit, validation of form works fine and if any mandatory field is blank,it shows error in red "You must specify a value for this required field."

Issue is If I mark DateTime field as mandatory  then mandatory validation is not working properly.It is not validating all mandatory fields and showing message in red on submitting/adding new record.
This is issue only when using custom form,not in default newform.aspx.

I saw [similar issue here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/37c49dfd-cd7d-4775-9aec-ebff658b6a4c/mandatory-date-field-validation-different-if-using-a-custom-form-why?forum=sharepointgeneral) but not proper answer why this is occuring and how to resolve?

```
<tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>Date of Discovery<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span></nobr>
                                <i  class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
                                 <span class="tooltip-text">
                                  Please enter date of discovery.
                                 </span>

                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="700px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff8{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Date_x0020_of_x0020_Discovery" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff8',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Date_x0020_of_x0020_Discovery')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff8description{$Pos}" FieldName="Date_x0020_of_x0020_Discovery" ControlMode="New"/>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Can you add the code you are using in your custom form to your question? that will be helpful to answer your question if you are missing anything.

Comment: updated with sample code for one of the field